# What dictates whether I should use sec=ntlm or sec=ntlmv2 in my mount options?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, ntlm

I'm mounting the same cifs share on two Ubuntu machines using the same credentials.  On one machine, I have to use `sec=ntlm` in the options, or it fails with `mount error(22): Invalid argument`; on the other I have to use `sec=ntlmv2`, or it fails with the same error.

I initially thought that it was the version of the OS that dictated which I would end up having to use, but I now realise that both machines are the same OS: Ubuntu 16.04.7.

If it's not the OS version, what is it that means I have to use `sec=ntlm` on one and `sec=ntlmv2` on the other?  It seems random but I'm sure it's not!

Comment: Do you have the same version of cifs-utils (mount.cifs -V)? Are you always mounting the same share, using the same UNC path, the same "domain\user", etc? How do both machines react to mounting with `sec=ntlmssp` (which is actually the recommended choice, instead of ntlm/ntlmv2)? Does `dmesg` show a more detailed error message after a failed mount?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, @user1686.  They are both using the same version of `cifs-utils` (6.4) and the mounting is absolutely identical except for whether I use `ntlm` or `ntlmv2`.  Where I use `ntlm`, if I try `ntlmssp` instead, I get `mount error(13): Permission denied` (and `dmesg` just confirms that error number); where I use `ntlmv2`, if I try `ntlmssp` instead, it works fine.

Comment: Do both computers have the same operating system at same level? And the cifs server?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, as mentioned, both computers are Ubuntu 16.04.7 and have unattended upgrades enabled.  I assume by "the cifs server" you are asking what that is?  It's a QNAP NAS, but it's not mine so I don't know much about it.

Comment: Are the two mount commands truly identical without even one character difference? Does `dmesg` show something interesting? What happens with no `sec` parameter at all?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, they are absolutely 100% identical (except that one has to be `ntlm` and one `ntlmv2`).  Nothing interesting shown by `dmesg` - or rather nothing that I don't see in the output of the `mount` command.  And if I don't include the `sec` parameter at all, it still works in the `ntlmv2` one but gives a `mount error(13): Permission denied` error in the `ntlm` one.

Comment: This is not logical - there must be some difference between the two computers, perhaps a missing or not-upgraded package.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129604/discussion-between-ipsrich-and-harrymc).